# ability to follow all area51 sites, even when in commitment-phase

Tags: feature-request, support, area-51, commitment-phase, following-proposal

I would like to bookmark area51 sites of my interest, so I can retrieve them when logged in. Right now I can do this by following them, which is fine. But for the sites that are already in the commitment phase I must commit in order to bookmark them. There are sites I want to follow, but don't have the time to commit to....

So to summarise; feature request to always be able to follow sites, even if they are already in the commitment or beta phase

Answer (score 6):

In Area 51, when you view a site proposal that's already in Commitment phase, it will, *by default*, show you the Commitment view.

**However**, you can still click the "definition" tab (towards top right of the page) to go back and see the Definition view.  Alternatively, you can append `"?phase=definition"` (without quotes)  to the URL.

Then, once you're in the Definition view, you can click the **"Follow it!"** link.

Voilà, you have just followed (*not* committed to) a proposal in the Commitment phase.

Comment: (Of course, it would be better if they just had a "Follow it!" link somewhere on the Commitment view page.)

Comment: Doesn't work for me anymore, just tried it on the SciFi private beta.  I second the request, I'd love to be able to follow something at any phase.